# Getting "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" when querying the chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I'm using fabric-sdk-go to install, instantiate, invoke and querying the chaincode.

1. chaincode installation is successful.

   ```
   root@991bc7577959:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode list --installed
   Get installed chaincodes on peer:
    Name: myproject, Version: 1.0, Path: github.com/hyperledger/myproject/chaincode/, Id: 130607a18ab3fe332854d7c2048f04b89e3c740e1ffa97c76c9ced266e6714ca
   ```
2. chaincode instantiation.

   #### Snippet of code

   ```
   ccPolicy := cauthdsl.SignedByAnyMember([]string{"Seller", "Buyer"})
   fmt.Println("Value of ccPolicy is: ", ccPolicy)
   resp, err := setup.admin.InstantiateCC(setup.ChannelID, 
   resmgmt.InstantiateCCRequest{
       Name:    setup.ChainCodeID,
       Path:    setup.ChaincodeGoPath,
       Version: "1.0",
       Args:    [][]byte{[]byte("init"), []byte("Seller"), []byte("100"), []byte("Buyer"), []byte("200")},
       Policy: ccPolicy,
   })
   ```

checking the docker container

```
root@991bc7577959:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode list --instantiated -C mychannel
 Get instantiated chaincodes on channel mychannel:
   Name: myproject, Version: 1.0, Path: github.com/hyperledger/myproject/chaincode/, Input: <nil>, Escc: escc, Vscc: vscc
```

### Here the chaincode is instantiated but the Input tag is showing nil value. Is it expected? Isn't it suppose to show the values that I've used for instantiation

3. Querying the chaincode

   #### snippet of code

   ```
   func (setup *FabricSetup) Query(OrgName string) (string, error) {
       fmt.Println("\n Calling query method")
       // Prepare arguments
       var args []string
       args = append(args, OrgName)
       response, err := setup.client.Query(channel.Request{
           ChaincodeID: setup.ChainCodeID,
           Fcn:         "invoke",
           Args:        [][]byte{[]byte("query"), []byte(args[0])}})
       if err != nil {
           return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to query: %v", err)
       }

       fmt.Println("\n Query chaincode ended")
       return string(response.Payload), err
   }
   ```

this querying of chaincode is resulting in below error:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>
> > [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x9e17e0]
> >
> > goroutine 1 [running]:
> >     github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/channel.(*Client).Query(0x0, 0xdb43d4, 0x9, 0xdb14ef, 0x6, 0xc00016ff80, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
> >     /home/alpha/GoWorkspace/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/channel/chclient.go:97 +0xc0
> >     github.com/hyperledger/myproject/sdk.(*FabricSetup).Query(0xc000179ea8, 0xdb0f3d, 0x6, 0x0, 0xdbbe50, 0x13, 0xdb43cb) >/home/alpha/GoWorkspace/src/github.com/hyperledger/myproject/sdk/query.go:17 +0x2d4
> >     main.main()
> >             /c/Projects/Go/src/github.com/hyperledger/myproject/main.go:79 +0x176

setup.go: file for creating a channel, installing and instantiating chaincode

```
import packages
type FabricSetup struct {
    ConfigFile      string
    OrgID           string
    OrdererID       string
    ChannelID       string
    ChainCodeID     string
    initialized     bool
    ChannelConfig   string
    ChaincodeGoPath string
    ChaincodePath   string
    OrgAdmin        string
    OrgName         string
    UserName        string
    client          *channel.Client
    admin           *resmgmt.Client
    adminIdentity   *msp.SigningIdentity
    sdk             *fabsdk.FabricSDK
    event           *event.Client
}

// Initialize reads the configuration file and sets up the client, chain and event hub
func (setup *FabricSetup) Initialize() error {
    // Step 1: creates the channel and updates all of the anchor peers for all orgs
    identityManagerClientContext := setup.sdk.Context(fabsdk.WithUser(setup.OrgAdmin), fabsdk.WithOrg(setup.OrgName))
    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to load Admin identity")
    }

    fmt.Printf("\n Step 2.a: Value of identityManagerClientContext is: ", identityManagerClientContext)

    // Channel management client is responsible for managing channels (create/update channel)
    chMgmtClient, err := resmgmt.New(identityManagerClientContext)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to create channel management client from Admin identity")
    }

    setup.admin = chMgmtClient
    mspClient, err := mspclient.New(setup.sdk.Context(), mspclient.WithOrg(setup.OrgName))
    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to create MSP client")
    }
    adminIdentity, err := mspClient.GetSigningIdentity(setup.OrgAdmin)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to get admin signing identity")
    }
    setup.adminIdentity = &adminIdentity
    fmt.Println("Initialization Successful")
    setup.initialized = true
    return nil
}

// CreateChannel for creating channel between the Organizations
func (setup *FabricSetup) CreateChannel() error {

    req := resmgmt.SaveChannelRequest{
        ChannelID:         setup.ChannelID,
        ChannelConfigPath: setup.ChannelConfig,
        SigningIdentities: []msp.SigningIdentity{*setup.adminIdentity},
    }
    txID, err := setup.admin.SaveChannel(req, resmgmt.WithOrdererEndpoint(setup.OrdererID))
    if err != nil || txID.TransactionID == "" {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to save channel")
    }
    fmt.Println("Channel created")
    return nil
}

// joins all peers in all of the given orgs to the given channel
func (setup *FabricSetup) JoinChannel() error {
    // Make admin user join the previously created channel
    if err := setup.admin.JoinChannel(
        setup.ChannelID,
        resmgmt.WithRetry(retry.DefaultResMgmtOpts),
        resmgmt.WithOrdererEndpoint(setup.OrdererID)); err != nil {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to make admin join channel")
    }
    fmt.Println("Channel joined")
    return nil
}

// InstallCC to install and instantiate the chaincode
func (setup *FabricSetup) InstallCC() error {

    // Create the chaincode package that will be sent to the peers
    ccPkg, err := packager.NewCCPackage(setup.ChaincodePath, setup.ChaincodeGoPath)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to create chaincode package")
    }
    fmt.Println("ccPkg created")

    // Install example cc to org peers
    installCCReq := resmgmt.InstallCCRequest{
        Name:    setup.ChainCodeID,
        Path:    setup.ChaincodePath,
        Version: "1.0", //chaincode version. first version of chaincode
        Package: ccPkg,
    }
    _, err = setup.admin.InstallCC(installCCReq, resmgmt.WithRetry(retry.DefaultResMgmtOpts))
    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to install chaincode")
    }
    fmt.Println("Chaincode installed")
    return nil
}

// InstantiateCC for instantiating the chaincode
func (setup *FabricSetup) InstantiateCC() error {
    // Set up chaincode policy
    ccPolicy := cauthdsl.SignedByAnyMember([]string{"Seller", "Buyer"})
    fmt.Println("Value of ccPolicy is: ", ccPolicy)

    resp, err := setup.admin.InstantiateCC(setup.ChannelID, resmgmt.InstantiateCCRequest{
        Name:    setup.ChainCodeID,
        Path:    setup.ChaincodeGoPath,
        Version: "1.0",
        Args:    [][]byte{[]byte("init"), []byte("Seller"), []byte("100"), []byte("Buyer"), []byte("200")},
        //Args:   [][]byte{[]byte("init")},
        Policy: ccPolicy,
    })
    if err != nil || resp.TransactionID == "" {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to instantiate the chaincode")
    }
    fmt.Println("Chaincode instantiated")

    // Channel client is used to query and execute transactions
    clientContext := setup.sdk.ChannelContext(setup.ChannelID, fabsdk.WithUser(setup.UserName))
    setup.client, err = channel.New(clientContext)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to create new channel client")
    }
    fmt.Println("Channel client created")

    // Creation of the client which will enables access to our channel events
    setup.event, err = event.New(clientContext)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to create new event client")
    }
    fmt.Println("Event client created")

    fmt.Println("Chaincode Installation & Instantiation Successful")
    return nil
}

// CloseSDK to close the sdk connection
func (setup *FabricSetup) CloseSDK() {
    setup.sdk.Close()
}
```

2. main.go file: calling all the methods in this file

   ```
   func initializeChannelAndCC(fSetup sdk.FabricSetup) {
       err := fSetup.CreateChannel()
       if err != nil {
           fmt.Printf("Unable to create channel: %v\n", err)
       }
       err = fSetup.JoinChannel()
       if err != nil {
           fmt.Printf("Unable to join channel: %v\n", err)
       }
       err = fSetup.InstallCC()
       if err != nil {
           fmt.Printf("Unable to install the chaincode: %v\n", err)
       }
       err = fSetup.InstantiateCC()
       if err != nil {
           fmt.Printf("Unable to instantiate the chaincode: %v\n", err)
       }
   }

   func main() {
       fSetup := sdk.FabricSetup{
           OrdererID: "orderer.mytrade.com",
           ChannelID:     "mychannel",
           ChannelConfig: "/c/Projects/Go/src/github.com/hyperledger/myproject/network/channel-artifacts/channel.tx",
           ChainCodeID:     "myproject",
           ChaincodeGoPath: "/c/Projects/Go",
           ChaincodePath:   "github.com/hyperledger/myproject/chaincode/",
           OrgAdmin:        "Admin",
           OrgName:         "Seller",
           ConfigFile:      "config.yaml",
           UserName: "User1",
       }

       err := fSetup.Initialize()
       if err != nil {
           fmt.Printf("Unable to initialize the Fabric SDK: %v\n", err)
           return
       }
       defer fSetup.CloseSDK()
       initializeChannelAndCC(fSetup)
       response, err := fSetup.Query("Seller")
       if err != nil {
           fmt.Printf("Unable to query the chaincode: %v\n", err)
       } else {
           fmt.Printf("Response from the query: %s\n", response)
       }
   }
   ```

client-side logging(set to debug mode). These logs are huge hence sharing the link [ClientLogs](https://justpaste.it/33gwm)

Please help.

### EDIT: added chaincode

```
type SimpleChaincode struct {
}

// Init method: one time initialisation
func (t *SimpleChaincode) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    fmt.Println("ex02 Init")
    _, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
    var A, B string    // Entities
    var Aval, Bval int // Asset holdings
    var err error

    if len(args) != 4 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 4")
    }

    test := strings.Join(args, ", ")
    fmt.Println("Value of args is: ", test)

    // Initialize the chaincode
    A = args[0]
    Aval, err = strconv.Atoi(args[1])
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Expecting integer value for asset holding")
    }
    B = args[2]
    Bval, err = strconv.Atoi(args[3])
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Expecting integer value for asset holding")
    }
    fmt.Printf("A = %s, Aval = %d, B = %s, Bval = %d\n", A, Aval, B, Bval)

    // Write the state to the ledger
    err = stub.PutState(A, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Aval)))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }

    err = stub.PutState(B, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Bval)))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }

    return shim.Success(nil)
}

// Invoke method: used to sedn the request to the various custom methods
func (t *SimpleChaincode) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    fmt.Println("ex02 Invoke")
    function, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
    if function == "invoke" {
        // Make payment of X units from A to B
        return t.invoke(stub, args)
    } else if function == "delete" {
        // Deletes an entity from its state
        return t.delete(stub, args)
    } else if function == "query" {
        // the old "Query" is now implemtned in invoke
        return t.query(stub, args)
    }

    return shim.Error("Invalid invoke function name. Expecting \"invoke\" \"delete\" \"query\"")
}

// Transaction makes payment of X units from A to B
func (t *SimpleChaincode) invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    var A, B string    // Entities
    var Aval, Bval int // Asset holdings
    var X int          // Transaction value
    var err error

    fmt.Println("Value of args in invoke is: ", strings.Join(args, ", "))
    if len(args) != 3 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 3")
    }

    A = args[0]
    B = args[1]

    // Get the state from the ledger
    // TODO: will be nice to have a GetAllState call to ledger
    Avalbytes, err := stub.GetState(A)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Failed to get state")
    }
    if Avalbytes == nil {
        return shim.Error("Entity not found")
    }
    Aval, _ = strconv.Atoi(string(Avalbytes))

    Bvalbytes, err := stub.GetState(B)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Failed to get state")
    }
    if Bvalbytes == nil {
        return shim.Error("Entity not found")
    }
    Bval, _ = strconv.Atoi(string(Bvalbytes))

    // Perform the execution
    X, err = strconv.Atoi(args[2])
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Invalid transaction amount, expecting a integer value")
    }
    Aval = Aval - X
    Bval = Bval + X
    fmt.Printf("Aval = %d, Bval = %d\n", Aval, Bval)

    // Write the state back to the ledger
    err = stub.PutState(A, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Aval)))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }

    err = stub.PutState(B, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Bval)))
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }

    return shim.Success(nil)
}

// Deletes an entity from state
func (t *SimpleChaincode) delete(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    if len(args) != 1 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 1")
    }

    A := args[0]

    // Delete the key from the state in ledger
    err := stub.DelState(A)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("Failed to delete state")
    }

    return shim.Success(nil)
}

// query callback representing the query of a chaincode
func (t *SimpleChaincode) query(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    fmt.Println("Inside query method")
    var A string // Entities
    var err error

    fmt.Println("\value of args in query method is: ", strings.Join(args, ", "))
    if len(args) != 1 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting name of the person to query")
    }

    A = args[0]

    // Get the state from the ledger
    Avalbytes, err := stub.GetState(A)
    if err != nil {
        jsonResp := "{\"Error\":\"Failed to get state for " + A + "\"}"
        return shim.Error(jsonResp)
    }

    if Avalbytes == nil {
        jsonResp := "{\"Error\":\"Nil amount for " + A + "\"}"
        return shim.Error(jsonResp)
    }

    jsonResp := "{\"Name\":\"" + A + "\",\"Amount\":\"" + string(Avalbytes) + "\"}"
    fmt.Printf("Query Response:%s\n", jsonResp)
    return shim.Success(Avalbytes)
}

func main() {
    err := shim.Start(new(SimpleChaincode))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error starting Simple chaincode: %s", err)
    }
}
```

### EDIT

1. After the run time error, I logged in to `peer0.seller.mytrade.com` cli using the command 
   `docker exec -it cli bash` and ran the `peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n myproject -c '{"Args":["query","Seller"]}'` command to query the chaincode and I got the result `Seller = 100`.
2. Before running the `peer chaincode query` command, the `dev-peer0.seller.mytrade.com` container was missing. Only container `dev-peer1.seller.mytrade.com` exist. But after the  `peer chaincode query` command on `peer0.seller.mytrade.com` cli resulted in the chaincode container. Since the chaincode invoked on both the peers of Seller then both the containers should be there.
3. I also added 20s delay because I thought that docker is taking some time to create the container. But it didn't work.
4. PFA the image of `docker ps -a` command
   [image: docker ps -a output]

Comment: I encountered a similar problem, you have found a way to solve it?

Comment: not yet. someone suggested me to use `CouchDB` instead of `LevelDB` and currently, I'm working on it.

Comment: Try my example: https://github.com/batazor/hyperledger-fabric